# How to post to page as an app?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, jakarta-ee, restfb

So, I have an app (facebook app entity), and I have a page. I want to post to the page using the app, through the java code (by restfb, or any other suggestion). Looks like I am missing the phase where the page gives permission to the app to post. No idea how to do it.
Thank you all.
Uri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only post "as Page", not "as App". You need a Page Access Token and you need to use the /page-id/feed endpoint to post. Links with information and example code:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Comment: Thanks, so I can't post as an app, I can live with that. So, now I checked my permissions on the page through the graph api, and I see it is " public_profile, basic_info, manage_pages, user_friends ", which probably explains the error I get when I try to post "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action", probably missing the "publish_actions" permission. so, the followup question would be - how do I grant "publish_actions"? I am set as the admin of the page.

Comment: you set the permission like every other permission, in the scope parameter.