# Post as page admin on my facebook page through php backend service

Tags: php, facebook, web-services, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to post something on my own page as the admin or even as the page in facebook.
It is not related to the user and i do not want the user to log in through their account.
I tried using the facebook graph sdk and created an www app in facebook. But everything i try relates to a user signing in and then posting. I do NOT have to use it in my website and only need to post when the service is called.

How would i implement this?

Comment: You have to login as a user. Then you get a page access token for that user.

Comment: @WizKid:- I am not using a website to login the user. I need to post as the admin of a page on the same page when a user calls a backend service. How would I login as a user? Is that possible through php code?

Comment: You need to pop the login dialog somewhere. Then you can extend that access token for one that is valid up to 60 days

Comment: I cant pop any dialog boxes. The overall process for me is as follows  Client clicks a button on android application -> clicking calls a web service written in php -> the php has to share the data on facebook in my page. I am not using any website or any user interaction.

Comment: Then pop login in the Android application

Answer (score 0):

You need a Page Access Token and you need to use the /page-id/feed endpoint to post. You only get a Page Token by authorizing an admin of the Page with the "manage_pages" permission, but you can create an Extended Page Token that is valid forever so you only have to authorize the user one time.

Links with information and example code:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Another thread about this: [How to post to page as an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219104/how-to-post-to-page-as-an-app/26219333#comment41122678_26219333)