# how to request permission to post ads on a page as an app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working on a facebook app that posts newsfeed ads, and I have been banging my head against the wall for the last few days, the work flow *should* go like this:

1. User provides his page id.
2. The App requests authorization to post ads on the page. *stuck here*
3. App verifies that the user authorized it.
4. App creates adcreatives using the user's `page_id` in the `object_story_spec` call to `/adcreative` using the app's ad account.

I went through [How to post to page as an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219104/how-to-post-to-page-as-an-app)'s docs, couldn't figure it out.

- the app is written in Go, however if you can provide a code sample it doesn't matter what language you use, I just need the basic work flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do exactly, but if you want to create ads (for am ad_account/user) via an app, you'll need the `ads_management` permission during Facebook Login.

How you manually create a login flow can be found in the docs as well.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-extended
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: I need to post an newsfeed ad from my app, but using my ad account, not the user's.

Comment: The ad account is always linked to a user

Comment: I understand that, but I need to use "my" ad account to post to the user's page.

Comment: Sure, that's what Facebook Login is for. It's all in the docs